# VirtualBox Ubuntu couldn't not open the medium ubuntu 18.04.4-amd64.iso

Tags: virtualbox, disk

I have a problem at VirtualBox. At the settings,when I open Storage and add the Optical Drive,the ubuntu one doesn't work,only the windows7 disk I downloaded.
When I start my Virtual Machine it says that : "FATAL:No bootable medium found!System halted."
Is there a way how to fix this with the ubuntu one not the windows7 optical drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open VirtualBox, select the guest OS, click the gear-shaped Settings icon ⚙️ located on the VirtualBox menu bar, click Storage, click the dropdown triangle under the CD image to the right of where it says Optical Drive, and select *Choose Virtual Optical Disk File...*.

Choose a virtual optical disk or a physical drive to use with the virtual drive. The virtual machine will see a disk inserted into the drive with the data in the file or on the disk in the physical drive as its contents.

[image: VirtualBox]

Comment: Did not help... For what reason the "Controller: SATA" item has a red dot behind its icon?

Comment: @abc The red dot is an emblem that indicates that some object is connected to Controller: SATA.